# Error: Unable to list kernel events: Kernel tracer not available (LTTNG)

Tags: c++, eclipse, lttng

I have just started to get my hands around with lttng and have not idea why I get this error when I try to execute the following command: sudo lttng list -k. I am using Eclipse and cross-compiling my C++ code on the Arm processor. I refered to several links but none seem to solve my error. I am able to generate a user space trace but the problem comes with the kernel tracing.

Can someone pleaseee help me. I am in real need of help.

I did this as of now.

```
sudo lttng creat mytest --ouput=/home/user/test
sudo lttng enable-channel -k -a ( i get error here)
sudo lttng enable-channel -u -a (this works)
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Mathieu Desnoyers can you please help me?

Comment: @Francis Giraldeau Can you also help me?

Answer (score 0):

We'll need a lot more information from you, like the error message for a start. Also, the linux distribution, the version of lttng, how it was installed, etc.